# Block IP Addresses using Code

Tags: code, ip

Is there a way (which I am sure there is) to block IP addresses using code. I want the code to be in PHP so that I can put it in my child themes function.php to use for block some IP addresses. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place in your template's `index.php` the following piece of code:

```
$deny = array("127.0.0.1", "88.88.88.88");

if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) 
{
    header("Location: http://example.com");
    die();
}
```

And just change the addresses of `$deny` for the IP address or addresses you want to block.